# Python exception handling ValueError

Tags: python, valueerror, except

Why does the `except ValueError as ve` block does not get executed , when I pass a character?

```
class Division :
    def divide(numerator, denominator):
        try:
            print(f"Result  : {(numerator/denominator)}")
        except ValueError as ve:
            print("Invalid input given",ve)
        except Exception as e :
            print(f"Exception caught : {e} ")

    if __name__ == "__main__" :
        a = int(input("Enter the numerator - "))
        b = int(input("Enter the denominator - "))
        divide(a,b)
```

O/P:

```
Enter the numerator - A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in Division
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A'
```

Instead I want to see `print("Invalid input given",ve)` getting executed.

Comment: It does not make sense to use a `class` like this, at all.

Comment: The error is happening on the `int(input(...))` line, before you even call `divide()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the trace information in your error, the exception is not being thrown by your `divide` function. If you use the code below to collect the user input without casting, you can avoid throwing this exception outside of your divide function.

```
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    a = input("Enter the numerator - ")
    b = input("Enter the denominator - ")
    divide(a,b)
```

As Karl pointed out in the comment, you will need to cast the values to int inside your divide function instead to generate the ValueError there. Otherwise, it will throw a TypeError.

Comment: Okay, but this doesn't meaningfully solve the problem. `input` will return a string no matter what the user types. The division will fail with a `TypeError`, not triggering the clause OP wants.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - Fair point. The OP would have to either handle that additional error or perform the cast in the divide function.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's this line that generate an error:

`a = int(input("Enter the numerator - "))`

You try to convert to integer a character.